# what is the mathematical logic of this solution (finding a number that is a multiple of numbers 1 to 20)

Tags: ruby

2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

I already found a solution but it was almost brute forcing which took about 7 seconds to run until it found the solution.

I found answers on stackoverflow but couldn't understand the logic behind finding the answer. I know what LCM and GCM are but how did he figure out to use them this way to find the answer? (which is 232,792,560)

```
def find_multiple
  lcm = 1

  (2..20).each do |i|
    lcm *= i / gcd(lcm, i)
  end

  lcm
end

def gcd(a, b)
  while b > 0
    a %= b
    return b if a == 0
    b %= a
  end

  a
end

puts find_multiple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shorter way, using the built in `lcm` method of Integer

```
p (2..20).inject(&:lcm)  # => 232792560
```

"lcm"  means "least common multiple". (To refresh your memory: the lcm is useful when adding or subtracting fractions with different denominators). The code above is an extremely terse way of coding the following process:

- Take 2 and 3, calculate the lcm, which is 6.
- With this 6, calculate
  the lcm with the next number, 4. The result is 12.
- Calculate the lcm
  of 12 and 5. Result 60
- Calculate the lcm of 60 and 6. Result 60
- etc. all the way upto 20

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail, the goal of my question was understanding the logic behind finding the answer, not necessarily the answer itself which ive already found answers same exact as yours online. thanks anyway though

Comment: @aimenalt added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Every non-negative integer can be expressed by its prime decomposition. Therefore, every number divisible by all numbers between `2` and `20` can be expressed

```
2**n2 * 3**n3 * 5**n5 * 7**n7 * 11**n11 * 13**n13 * 17**n17 * 19**n19
```

`2`, `3`,  `5`,  `7`,  `11`,  `13`,  `17` and `19` are the primes between `2` and `20`, and the values of the exponents are to be determined.

Ruby provides a method [Prime::prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division) that the returns the prime decomposition of a number. Let's compute the prime decomposition of every number between `2` and `20`:

```
(2..20).each { |n| puts "#{n}: #{Prime.prime_division(n)}" }
 2: [[2, 1]]
 3: [        [3, 1]]
 4: [[2, 2]]
 5: [                [5, 1]]
 6: [[2, 1], [3, 1]]
 7: [                        [7, 1]]
 8: [[2, 3]]
 9: [        [3, 2]]
10: [[2, 1],         [5, 1]]
11: [                                [11, 1]]
12: [[2, 2], [3, 1]]
13: [                                         [13, 1]]
14: [[2, 1],                 [7, 1]]
15: [[3, 1],         [5, 1]]
16: [[2, 4]]
17: [                                                  [17, 1]]
18: [[2, 1], [3, 2]]
19: [                                                           [19, 1]]
20: [[2, 2],         [5, 1]]
```

`12`, for example, equals `2**2 * 3**1`, expressed `[2,2], [3,1]`. Each two-tuple is of the form `[p,e]`, where `p` is the prime and `e` is the exponent.

Now consider each prime between `2` and `20`. We see that every even number requires `2` raised to a power, the maximum of which is `4`, for `16`.that  This tells us that every number `n` divisible by every number between `2` and `20` must be divisible by `2**4`. If `n` is divisible by `2**4`, it is of course also divisible by `2**1`, `2**2` and `2**3`, thereby satisfying the requirements of all other even numbers between `2` and `20`. It follows that `n2` in the above expression must be at least `4`. Since we want the smallest product of the primes raised to a power, we set `n2` to `4`.

For the prime `3`. the exponents are seen to `1`, `1`, `2`, `1` and `2` for the five numbers between `2` and `20` that are divisible by `3`. All numbers divisible by all numbers between `2` and `20` therefore must be divisible by `3**2`. We therefore set `n3` to `2`.

Repeating this for each of the remaining primes `5`, `7`, `11`, `13`, `17` and `19`, we see that the smallest number divisible by all numbers between `2` and `20` equals

```
2**4 * 3**2 * 5**1 * 7**1 * 11**1 * 13**1 * 17**1 * 19**1
  #=> 232792560
```

Ruby has another method, [Prime::Prime.int_from_prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-int_from_prime_division) that produces this number from the form of the array returned by `prime_division`:

```
Prime.int_from_prime_division([[2,4], [3,2], [5,1], [7,1], [11,1], [13,1],
  [17,1], [19,1]])
  #=> 232792560
```

We can wrap this up into the following calculation.

```
def smallest_divisible_by_2_to_n(n)
  Prime.int_from_prime_division(
    (2..n).each_with_object({}) do |n,h|
      Prime.prime_division(n).each { |p,e| h[p] = [h[p].to_i, e].max }
    end.to_a)
end
```

Note that if the hash `h` does not have a key `p`, `h[p] #=> nil`. It is for that reason that I have written `h[p].to_i`, as `nil.to_i #=> 0`. See [Nilclass#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i). That method is precisely for situations such as this one.

```
smallest_divisible_by_2_to_n(10)
  #=> 2520
smallest_divisible_by_2_to_n(20)
  #=> 232792560
smallest_divisible_by_2_to_n(30)
  #=> 2329089562800
```